# Unable to proceed after denying for all permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to ask the user for `Camera, Location, Write Storage, CallPhone` permissions and show an alert dialog when user denies any of the permissions.

But my code throws this exception :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: fwt_android.mpermissions, PID: 4850
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {fwt_android.mpermissions/fwt_android.mpermissions.activities.Splash}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>                                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
>                                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
>                                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:226)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:260)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
>                                                                                   at fwt_android.mpermissions.activities.Splash.onRequestPermissionsResult(Splash.java:215)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6553)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6432)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Here are the constants for checking permissions -

```
private final int PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT = 1;
private final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING = 1;
String[] permissionsRequired = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};
```

Here is my code for checking permisions -

```
public void checkPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissionsRequired[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissionsRequired[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissionsRequired[2]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissionsRequired[3]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
           ) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Splash.this, permissionsRequired[0])
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Splash.this, permissionsRequired[1])
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Splash.this, permissionsRequired[2])
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Splash.this, permissionsRequired[3])) {

            //Show Information about why you need the permission
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Need Multiple Permissions");
            builder.setMessage("This app needs Camera Location, Storage and Phone permissions.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Splash.this, permissionsRequired, PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            }).create().show();
        } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(permissionsRequired[0], false)
                || permissionStatus.getBoolean(permissionsRequired[1], false)
                || permissionStatus.getBoolean(permissionsRequired[2], false)
                || permissionStatus.getBoolean(permissionsRequired[3], false)
                ) {
            //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
            // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Need Multiple Permissions");
            builder.setMessage("This app needs Camera, Location, Storage and Phone permissions.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    sentToSettings = true;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant  Camera and Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            }).create().show();
        } else {
            //just request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Splash.this, permissionsRequired, PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
        }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(permissionsRequired[0], false);
        editor.putBoolean(permissionsRequired[1], false);
        editor.putBoolean(permissionsRequired[2], false);
        editor.putBoolean(permissionsRequired[3], false);
        editor.apply();
    } else {
        //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
        splashTread.start();
    }
}
```

And Here is the callback function -

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT) {
        //check if all permissions are granted
        boolean allgranted = false;
        for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
            if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                allgranted = true;
            } else {
                allgranted = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allgranted) {
            splashTread.start();
        } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Splash.this, permissions[0])
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Splash.this, permissions[1])
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Splash.this, permissions[2])
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Splash.this, permissions[3])) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Need Multiple Permissions");
            builder.setMessage("This app needs Camera, Location, Storage and Phone permissions.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Splash.this, permissionsRequired, PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            }).create().show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unable to get Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `splashThread()` functions is the function for waiting when all permissions are granted which is working correct but when I deny any permission and proceed so that a new alert dialog should be displayed to send the user to settings but the app crashes at the time of `builder.show();`

I don't know why I am getting this error even when I have debugged the whole class. 
Can you please help me finding out the error and its solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Got solution for my answer by rechecking the guidelines of Google for runtime permissions. As its stated [there](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) that the

```
ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()
```

should not block the thread for user response it should just show the user an explanation for permission requirement.

So, I did it by replacing

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Need Multiple Permissions");
            builder.setMessage("This app needs Camera, Location, Storage and Phone permissions.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Splash.this, permissionsRequired, PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            }).create().show();
```

with `checkPermission()` call